# Install two Windows 10 partitions (Mac - Win1 - Win2)

Tags: windows, bootcamp, dual-boot

I have a MacBook Retina with a 1 TB SSD.

I started with a Mac (387 GB) and a Win partition (400 GB), but now I need to add a tiny extra Windows partition (175 GB) to run a specific software.

What I’ve done so far:

- I created a partition using the disk utility and formatted it as exFAT
- I created a bootable Windows USB drive, it’s called “EFI Boot” when I view it through the turn on the computer while pressing <kbd>Opt</kbd> screen.
- I added the Windows support files to another USB drive
- I installed Windows through the usual turn on the computer while pressing the <kbd>Opt</kbd>, and clicking on the installation USB drive.
- Through the installation I was asked where I wanted to install my copy, I formatted my previously created partition to make it NTFS and then installed Windows on it.
- I connected my USB drive with the Windows support files and ran `Setup.exe` from the BootCamp folder to install the drivers. Then I restarted to apply the changes.

Now I’m on the turn on while pressing <kbd>Opt</kbd> window but I only see two partitions, my previous Windows partition is nowhere to be seen.

I went to Disk Utility on Mac to see if the partitions were okay and they seem to be, but now both are called BootCamp with the difference of the mounting point (`/Volumes/BOOTCAMP` vs `/Volumes/BOOTCAMP 1`)
so I’m thinking maybe that’s the issue.

Comment: Do you have a question? There is no question mark character (?) to be found in your post. Everything you posted is so far seems plausible and without error. You could have included more information to help narrow when the MacBook was made. Holding down the option key a startup should result in two icons appearing in the Mac Startup Manager. One is for Apple macOS (or OS X) and one is for Microsoft Windows. You made no effort for there to be a third icon for a second Window installation and I believe doing so would be unusual.

Comment: Hi David, the issue was that I couldn’t access my old windows partition only the new one. 

I did figured it out, it was all okay, just had to chose the partition from the windows settings